# Insert data in sqlite db when the activity is called first Time,stop inserting when return to the activity again or call the activity again

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

In my activity form where i entered events in sqlite but when i returned to this activity or again execute this activity again data entered in sqlite.
I check my DB file is full of duplicate or same data.
How can i prevent to entering data entered in sqlite again and again.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);


        // add events in database
        db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2016-01-15", "Location-House"));
        db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2016-01-15", "Location-House"));
        db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Birthday", "2016-01-18", "Location House"));
        db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("Mobile Computing", "2015-12-10", "Location- college"));
        db.addEvent(new CalendarEvent("31th December", "2015-12-31", "Party Location-House"));


        // get all books
        List<CalendarEvent> list = db.getAllEvent();
        CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr = new ArrayList<CalendarEvent>();
        CalendarEvent.event_calendar_arr.addAll(list);

{onCreate method from main activity and addEvent method from MySqliteHelper class}

public void addEvent(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {

        Log.d("addEvent", calendarEvent.toString());

        // get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EVENT_NAME, calendarEvent.getEventName()); // get event_name
        values.put(KEY_EVENT_DATE, calendarEvent.getEventDate()); // get event_date
        values.put(KEY_EVENT_DESC, calendarEvent.getEventDesc()); // get event_desc

        // insert values in event table
        db.insert(EVENT_TABLE, null, values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values
        //(table, nullColumnHack, values)

        // close
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to insert the same events everytime, the activity is created?

Comment: Then use `SharedPreferences` to store, that you already inserted the values. A code example would be, what @ρяσѕρєя K wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to data insert in sqlite database when first time activity call

Use `SharedPreferences` for executing database insert operation only once when application is launched first time:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
                       getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

if(!prefs.contains("insertedInDB")){
   // insert in DB

  // create key in prefs
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("insertedInDB", true);
   editor.commit();
}else{
   // no need to insert in db
}
```

Comment: but its also run if i want to enter new data

Comment: @user2222: when you want to insert data then you should need to delete  clear SharedPreferences using `editor.remove(insertedInDB);editor.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are entering it every time, the activity is created. The solution to ommit doulbe entries would be, to check wether this entry already exists in the database.

You could save in `SharedPreferences` a value, that you already inserted this entries to the database. You can imagine `SharedPreferences` like a table, which is very quick accessable and easy to use. To check it out, you could follow the Android Developer Guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

But you should think, if it is really necessary, that everytime the activity is created the same entries get inserted.